# Input me cambia de estilo con el autocompletado

Tags: html, css

He hecho un formulario de registro y cuando los inputs se autocompletan me cambia el estilo:

```css
    .input-entrar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto 15% -107.5%;
    width: 300%;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    background-color: #151515;
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #505050;
}
```

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

He probado a usar autocomplete:off pero en Google Chrome no me ha funcionado, además de que es matar moscas a cañonazos y preferiría usar otro método.

Comment: Por favor, comparte el código `HTML` y `CSS` completo para que pueda revisarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes realizar es que dentro de tu form, desactives la etiqueta autocompletar. Podrias hacerlo de esta manera

```
autocomplete="off"
```

en termino general

```
<form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="">
```

Salu2.

Answer (score 0):

Con esto cambias el fondo del autocompletado:

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #fff inset;
}
```

Con esto cambias el color del contenido:

```css
input:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #000;
}
```